# Loop over multiple response matches from previous request in Gatling / Scala

Tags: scala, gatling

I'm still pretty new to Gatling / Scala, so my apologies if I've misunderstood something obvious, but...

I have a scenario with a sequence of requests. One of them is along the lines of:

```
.exec (
  http("Get IDs")
  .post(<urlpath>)
  .body(<body text>)
  .headers(<headerinfo>)
  .check(jsonPath("$[*].some.json.path").findAll.transform(_.map(_.replace("unwantedchars,""))).saveAs(myIds)
)
```

And that works fine, returning a vector of all matching json elements, with the unwanted chars removed. What I'm trying to do next is loop over the first 5 ids, and pass them into the next request. I've tried assorted variants of the following, but no amount of variation / googling has returned the actual solution:

```
.exec( session => {
  val firstFive = session("myIds").as[Vector[String]].toArray.take(5)
  for (inx <- 0 until 4){
    exec(
      http("get the item")
        .get("/path/to/item/thing/" + firstFive(inx))
        .headers(<etc etc>)
      )
  session
})
```

So I understand nested exec's aren't supported - but how can I create a block that combines the for-loop, and the actual HTTP requests?

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: they have a section on looping: https://gatling.io/docs/current/advanced_tutorial#step-04-looping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're looking to take 5, then you just need to put them in the session and then process them with a .foreach block.

so instead of taking the first five and trying to make exec calls (which, as you observed, won't work), save the list back to the session

```
.exec( session => {
  val firstFive = session("myIds").as[Vector[String]].take(5)
  session.set("firstFive", firstFive)
)
```

then use the DSL to loop through the collection

```
.foreach("${firstFive}", "id") {
  exec(
    http("get the item")
      .get("/path/to/item/thing/${id}")
      .headers(<etc etc>)
  )
}
```

you could even add the selection of the first five to your transform step - so the whole thing could be...

```
.exec (
  http("Get IDs")
    .post(<urlpath>)
    .body(<body text>)
    .headers(<headerinfo>) .check(jsonPath("$[*].some.json.path").findAll.transform(_.map(_.replace("unwantedchars,"")).take(5).saveAs(myIds)
)
.foreach("${myIds}", "id") {
  exec(
    http("get the item")
      .get("/path/to/item/thing/${id}")
      .headers(<etc etc>)
  )
}
```

Comment: Still no joy. When i try your suggestion with the separate ``` exec(session => { val firstFive...``` block I get an error suggesting ```myIds``` is not in the session.... When I move to make the "take 5" to the transform, I get ```Condition evaluation crashed with message 'Can't cast value [Ljava.lang.String;@471ca58d of type class [Ljava.lang.String; into interface scala.collection.Seq', exiting loop``` ?

Comment: can you confirm before trying the session fuction that 'myIds' is in the session and what value it has?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance - as I say, I'm kinda new to Gatling - what's the best way to check that?

Comment: after your "Get Ids" request, you can use a session function to output session contents to the console. `.exec(session => {println(session); session})`

Comment: So myIDs is in the session.... I've now got as far as:

```.exec(session => {
  val firstFive= session ("myIds").as[Array[String]]
  for (id <- firstFive) {
    println("my/get/req/path/" + id) 
    exec(
    http("get the item") 
.get("/path/to/item/thing/" + id)
  .headers(<etc etc>)
    )}
  session
})
```
The println shows /my/get/req/path/xxxxx as appropriate for each id, but the "get the item" requests never get made?

Comment: You can't call dsl methods inside a session function. The exec block for using the ids needs to be chained after

Comment: I've done it!!! :)

Turns out the solution (for me at least!) is as per your suggestion above - "you could even add the selection....", however you need to remove the "toArray" bit from the transform there - just take 5 from the Vector, and it's job done!

Thank you so much for your support here!

Comment: (I've marked your answer as correct, but cannot upvote it (visibly) as I'm new to SO!)